# cakephp load partial view on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I am making a small search functionality where i have placed `.ctp` files into elements so that i can achieve ajax post without reloading the entire page and only render the element.

The element is very simple, it creates a `li` item with request data passed from the controller.

```
<li class="span2">
<a  class="pull-left" href="">
    <img  class="media-object" src="<?php $img_path = $result['Person']['profile_image']; echo $img_path;?>">
</a>
<div class="media-body">
    <label class="person-media">
        <?php
        $firstName = ucfirst($result['Person']['first_name']);
        $lastName = ucfirst($result['Person']['last_name']);

        echo $firstName;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $lastName;
        ?>
    </label>
</div>
```

In my search action, i want to keep the entire skeleton (header, footer, search div holder) and just render the list items in the unordered list. But on search click, the entire page loads

Here i am attempting to set the data

```
//transform POST into GET
    if($this->request->is("post")) {
        $url = array('action'=>'manage');
        $filters = array();

        if(isset($this->data['searchFor']) && $this->data['Search.name']){
            //maybe clean up user input here??? or urlencode??
            $filters['Search.name'] = $this->data['Search.name'];
        }
        //redirect user to the index page including the selected filters
        $this->redirect(array_merge($url,$filters));
    }

    $conditions = array();
    //
    // filter by name
    //
    if(isset($this->passedArgs['Search.name'])) {
        $conditions["Person.first_name LIKE"] = "%".$this->passedArgs["Search.name"]."%";

    }
    //paginate as normal
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'order' => array('Person.first_name ASC'),
        'limit' => 12
    );
    $this->layout = "main";
    $this->set("results",$this->paginate("Person"));
    **$this->render('manage');** // rendering on the element loads everything
```

After finding my results from the query, manage.ctp loads everything.

```
  </div>
<ul id="students-list" class="students-ist">
   <?php

    if(!empty($results)){

        foreach($results as $result){
            echo $this->element('singleuser', array('result' => $result));
        }
    }

    ?>

</ul>
```

How can i using Ajax and form submission load just an element inside a div without reloading the entire page on every search.

Comment: are you asking how to get full page with ajax but only load part of it( easily done), or how to modify the php to only send the partial? Or are you asking how to use AJAX?

Comment: i want to modify the php to only send the partial, on the button click, i would like to grab my result set and render the partial element which recreates all li elements. Right now it loads the entire page which is very unresponsive

Comment: OK...don't know much about Cake framework... but is very easy to use jQuery AJAX to request a full page from server, but only insert parts of it into active page in browser

Comment: Any way you could show an example of AJAX request that does this, i know how to get to my action controller and ultimately load the view but it renders a full page on each click

Comment: OK..start with, what is source of data you want to send? Can be an attribute of html element, or from text or part of href or????

Comment: the source data is the entire <li> elements, i don't have it in another form (JSON ..) and i am relying on cake php to route the data all the way through

Comment: right but I got impression you want some search data sent to server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21662/discussion-between-warz-and-charlietfl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get part of a full page from server and place only parts of it into page in browser.

Following is submit handler for search form that will make AJAX call. WIthin the AJAX complete callback will replace student list items with new ones

```
/* place code in script tag or external file after jQuery.js loads*/
$(function(){
    /* adjust selector to match ID of form*/
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
          /* sends form data retrieved in php as if form submitted through browser defalt method*/
           /* "this" is the form, serialize will formencode all fields in form*/
          var dataToServer=$(this).serialize();
          $.get( 'pageUrl.php', dataToServer, function(response){
                /* AJAX has returned page, "response" is the full html of page*/
               /* get the items from list from response*/
                var studentListItems= $(response).find('#students-list').html();

                /* replace the list items in active page*/
                $('#students-list').html(studentListItems);

           });
       /* prevent form default submit*/
       return false;
    });

})
```

Once you get Cake controller returning just the LI's you want, you can dump response straight into the list:

```
$('#students-list').html(response);
```